# MySQL searching for null and getting odd results

Tags: mysql, null, char

What I'm trying to do is find null characters in text_field.

I have a SQL statement that reads like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  text_field LIKE concat('%', char(0x00 using utf8), '%')
```

Interesting that if text_field contains NO NULL characters, but does contain `0xe2808e`, it will be selected with that SQL statement.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide a full example?

Comment: I don't know how to make it any more clear.  The SQL statement is exactly as you see it.  But it will return rows that have 0xe2808e  and that do NOT contain 0x00

Comment: We do not have your mytable or any references to the rows that are in it. Think of it from the point of view of somebody trying to answer - what is he going to try to see what you are seeing to be able to debug? Here is a good read on providing full examples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/  with that case? please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It's not really "legal" to store binary inside a text field. The database is expecting text to be.. well... text. You are just freaking up the encoding system.

Comment: Sure thing, but tell that to the users.. they cut and paste stuff from all over the place and sadly manage to inject all sorts of junk.... aside, all text is really binary - no?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly disregard - I was not able to recreate the issue using SQL Fiddle, but can easily do so from my production DB.  Obviously it must have to do with how the table is structured - or something else.